# Correlation's into a new CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, correlation

I have a hundred CSV file :

```
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed1.0_Buffer100.csv
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed1.0_Buffer200.csv
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed1.0_Buffer300.csv
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed2.0_Buffer100.csv
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed2.0_Buffer200.csv
Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed2.0_Buffer300.csv
...............
```

All CSV’s have structure data looks like this:

```
BS      Prediction  Ground truth
BS1-BS1  0          0
BS1-BS2  0          2
BS1-BS3  2         35
BS1-BS4  0          0
BS1-BS5  0          0
BS1-BS6  0          2
BS1-BS7  0          0
BS1-BS8  0          2
BS1-BS9  0          0
BS2-BS1  0          1
...............
```

I want to analyze the correlation between the prediction column and ground truth column. 
I used this code:

```
df['Prediction'].corr(df['Ground truth'])
```

If I analyzed one by one, it takes forever. 
Is it possible to analyze the correlation once and simultaneous build into one CSV file based on the files last title.? 
My expected result looks like this:

```
Files               Correlation
Speed1.0_Buffer100  0.65
Speed1.0_Buffer200  0.51
Speed1.0_Buffer300  0.73
Speed2.0_Buffer100  0.36
Speed2.0_Buffer200  0.59
Speed2.0_Buffer300  0.44
...............
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can csv file in your folder , read them

```
l=['Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed1.0_Buffer100.csv',
'Merge_Prediction_Groundtruth_Speed1.0_Buffer200.csv'
...]
```

like:

```
d={x: pd.read_csv(x) for x in l }
```

Then using `concat` with `groupby`

```
pd.concat(d).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x['Prediction'].corr(x['Groundtruth']))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing.